# Basic HTML: place images in one row with same distance from each other

Tags: css, html, positioning

My aim is to place 3 images in one row with the same distance from each other, as it is shown in the picture below (assuming the 2 arrows have the same length).

[image: As it should look like.]

By now my solution is a very ugly one, which breaks, if the window size is too small:

```
<h1>
    <div style="width:105px; height:30px; float:left; margin-top:25px;">
        <img src="image1.png"/>
    </div>
    <div style="width:190px; height:30px; float:left; margin-top:25px; margin-left:30%; margin-right:30%;">
        <img src="image2.png"/>
    </div>
    <div style="width:102px; height:30px; float:right; margin-top:25px;">
        <img src="image3.png"/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</h1>
```

I would really prefer a "clean" solution, but my HTML knowledge about positioning is too limited so far.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try to center div with margin:0 auto;

Comment: Is the width of your H1 fixed?

Comment: @Šime Vidas The width of H1 is not directly fixed, but I thing i inherits some fixed width from some parent element.

Comment: @KB But you say that "it breaks" if the window size is to small. If the H1 were fixed, it would always have the same width, and it wouldn't break.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Hm, I had a look at it again. There doesn't seem to be a fixed width indeed.

Comment: @KB Anyways, you can prevent the breaking by simply specifying the width on the H1 explicitly. So, you determine what width is needed for it to not break, and set that width on the H1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `text-align: justify`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BaGzL):

```
<div class="outer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x100" />
  <span class="fix"></span>
</div>
```

```
.outer {
    text-align: justify;
}
.outer img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: center;
}
.outer .fix {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

In most browsers, [you can remove that `.fix` span, and add](http://codepen.io/eric-wieser/pen/BAnIh):

```
.outer::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
}
```