# HTML/ CSS: A href exceeds linking image - how to avoid?

Tags: html, css, image, href

I put three HTML-elements in a row [using inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290085/basic-html-place-images-in-one-row-with-same-distance-from-each-other): 2 images linking to external websites (green boxes in the image below) and one div-tag with a search-form an a language selection.

The problem is now, that next to the images - on their right sides - there is also a hidden link. To make it visible I set ***text-decoration:underline*** and a blue background in active mode (see image).

How can I limit the ***a*** ***href*** to only the images?

[image: Problem: a href link exceeds image which it was meant for]

HTML code looks like that:

```
<div id="logo">
<a href="http://website1.example">
    <img src="image1.gif">
</a>
<a href="http://website2.example">
    <img src="image2.gif">
</a>
<div id="headermodules">
    <form class="search" method="post" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" value="Suchen...">
    </form>
    <div id="languageselection">
        <ul class="languageselection">
            <li id="active_language">
                <a href="http://localhost:81/de/">Deutsch</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://localhost:81/en/">English
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<span style="width: 100%;"></span>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like that:

```
#logo
{
position: relative;
height:129px;
text-align: justify;
z-index: 0;
border-top: 0px solid #000;
}
#logo  img 
{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#logo span
{
width: 100%;
height: 0;
display: inline-block;
}
#headermodules
{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: By using `background-image`for each `li` and than using `display: block;` for each `a` tag nested under `li`? you are doing totally wrong

Comment: @ Mr. Alien Could you give an example? The `li` are only in the third block (`div id="headermodules"`). I am struggeling with the `img` tags surrounded by `a href`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have the `a` elements styled to `inline-block` and not the `img`. The `img` should be `display: block`. I think that should do it.

```
#logo a { display: inline-block; }
#logo img { display: block; }
```