# <a> clickable area too large around image with img-responsive, center-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See http://codepen.io/robbielaldrich/pen/ZWJyjO?editors=1100.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.clashmusic.com/reviews/steve-reich-and-the-colin-currie-group-live-at-the-royal-festival-hall-london">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://clashmusic.com/sites/default/files/field/image/steve%20reich.jpg">
</a>
```

The `<a>` tag seems to be extending to the margin of the `<img>`, but I can't reduce the margin or the image will no longer be centered.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve, but how about centering the `<a>` tag, instead?

Comment: Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627469/html-css-a-href-exceeds-linking-image-how-to-avoid) out. Solution to your problem should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap's CSS is sets both `center-block` and `img-responsive` to `display: block`

A block level element becomes like a `<div>` and will take up the whole width of its container if a width or max-width isn't specified.  The anchor is wrapped around the entire image block, including the empty space.

You could override the `display: block` easy enough and center-align the image as if it were text:

```
<div class="text-center">
<a href="http://www.clashmusic.com/reviews/steve-reich-and-the-colin-currie-group-live-at-the-royal-festival-hall-london">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" style="display: inline-block !important;" src="http://clashmusic.com/sites/default/files/field/image/steve%20reich.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

But without knowing the context of the layout I can't say if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Why you dont use a div to wrap and halign your image?

see my code

HTML

```
<div class="text-center">
  <a href="http://www.clashmusic.com/reviews/steve-reich-and-the-colin-currie-group-live-at-the-royal-festival-hall-london">
    <img src="http://clashmusic.com/sites/default/files/field/image/steve%20reich.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img{
  display: inline-block
}
```

EDIT:

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grxjmK

Comment: The OP gave you a pen to work with. How about revising/updating the OP's pen to demonstrate your solution *(or press Ctrl+M and make your S.O. answer functional)?*